# How to create dynamic ManyToMany field in Django?

Tags: python, django

In admin add view I would like to able to select dynamically field A_permission from selected A-object while creating new B-object

```
A(models.Model):
 name = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=50)
 permission = models.CharField(max_length=50)

B(models.Model):
  A_name = models.ForeignKey(A)
  A_permissions = models.ManyToManyField(A)
```

So I have `objectA1` and `objectA2` for example. While creating `object B` I should be able to first select one of the `A objects`, and then just get its permission for selection in field `A_permissions`

Can someone please point me how to do this? I feel like I tried everything

Comment: Your data model seems unusual to me. If `A` has a unique name for each permission how can a record in `B` map to a name in `A` with a unique permission and at the same time map to a permission in `A` for another name? Do you want to be able to select multiple permissions from `A` when creating new object `B` or do you want to only select one permission from `A` for each new `B`? I can give answers to both use cases.

Comment: ```permission``` should hold multiple values, CharField is probably not the right field type but Ill go with any recommendation that would fit. So I would like to be able to select multiple ```permissions``` from ```A object ```selected in ```A_name```field  - so current model instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Further to the comments I made to your question, below is how I would allow selecting multiple permissions from A to one record in B.

In models.py:

```
class A(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=50)
    permission = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.name}: {self.permission}"

class B(models.Model):
    A_name = models.ManyToManyField(A)
```

In admin.py

```
from .models import A, B

admin.site.register(A)
admin.site.register(B)
```

Go to admin 
You should be able to select multiple Permissions from `A` in one record for `B` using shift+click or ctrl+click.

There are many good django tutorials out there. I find the [mozilla django tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Django) to be quite good.